# Probability of Sampling Points outside of the Empirical Span

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, concentration-of-measure

Let $P$ be a probability distribution over $\mathbb{R}^d$. Note that we DO NOT assume that $P$ is continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. For example, P can be a multinomial distribution over a finite and discrete set of points.

Let $D = \{x_1,...,x_n\}\sim P$ be n i.i.d. data sampled from $P$. Can we upperbound
$
\mathbb{P}_{x\sim P}\{x \notin span(D)\}?
$

In other words, given n points and their linear span $span(D) = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i| a_i\in\mathbb{R}, \forall i\right\}$, I want to bound the probability that a new point falls out of $span(D)$, as a function of $n$.

Comment: Is this an equivalent question? Suppose you have a bag with various balls of $d$ different colours and you sample with replacement $n+1$ times:  what is the maximum probability/supremum/upper bound of the probability that the $n+1$th ball drawn is a colour you have not previously seen?

Comment: ... assuming $n\ge d$.  Otherwise there will be easier continuous examples where the probability is $1$

Comment: @Henry they are slightly different. The problem you described is referred to as the couple collection problem, and there are some results w.r.t. that. The main difference is that here the axis of $span(D)$ is not fixed. If we frame the problem as the probability of reaching a new canonical axis that is not covered by D, then they will be equivalent.

Comment: OK but if $d=2$ and $n\ge d$, my alternative question seems to suggest $\frac1{2^n}$ as a maximum probability.  Could your original question have a different value?

Comment: @Henry, for $d=2$, they seem to get similar results, since after the 1st point, you can just use the first point (assuming it's nonzero) as the canonical axis for $span(D)$, and the rest is the same as the problem you defined. Though I think the answer is more like $1/\sqrt{n}$ by Markov inequality? How would you get $1/2^n$?

Comment: For my question and $d=2$, I maximised $p^n(1-p)+(1-p)^np$, but only looked at $n=2$ and $n=3$.  I no longer think $\frac1{2^n}$ is correct for $n\ge 4$